# Find multiple values in a range, within a group

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm using Hive, so HiveQL.

I have data that looks of the form:

```
placename              |  Value              |  id
A                      |  1.1                | 1
A                      |  1.05               | 2
A                      |  2                  | 3
A                      |  3                  | 4
B                      |  2                  | 1
B                      |  5                  | 2
B                      |  2.1                | 3
B                      |  7                  | 4
C                      |  1                  | 1
C                      |  2                  | 2
C                      |  3                  | 3
C                      |  17                 | 4
C                      |  17.11              | 5
C                      |  17.6               | 6
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to find a list of placenames and ids where there are multiple 'Value's within a given range.

I'm not sure - I'm not a SQL expert and don't have access to any in my organisation.

For example,

if I have a parameter valuerange, I want to find all placenames and ids where there are more than one Value within valuerange of another value. So, in the case where valuerange is 0.5, I would return:

- A - 1
- A - 2
- B - 1
- B - 3
- C - 4
- C - 5
- C - 6

because A has 1.1 and 1.05 - which are within 0.5 of one another, and so on for B and C. B - 1 and B -3 are here because values of 2.1 and 2 are within 0.5.

C -4, 5, 6 are found because 17, 17.11, 17.6 are within 0.5. 17 is within 0.5 of 17.11, and 17.6 is within 0.5 of 17.11.

Comment: Please explain the reason for B-1 and C-4 to be in the result.

Comment: added clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a self join of the table and the condition for the valuerange in the ON clause:

```
select distinct t.placename, t.id 
from tablename t inner join tablename tt 
on t.placename = tt.placename  
where t.id <> tt.id and tt.value between t.value - 0.5 and t.value + 0.5
order by t.placename, t.id
```

or with EXISTS:

```
select distinct t.placename, t.id 
from tablename t 
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where placename = t.placename and id <> t.id 
  and value between t.value - 0.5 and t.value + 0.5  
)
order by t.placename, t.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a3db1b98bd285c43eb9ecfa74dd1b24f)(for SQL Server but since the code is standard SQL I guess it will work for Hive too). 
Results:

```
> placename | id
> :-------- | -:
> A         |  1
> A         |  2
> B         |  1
> B         |  3
> C         |  4
> C         |  5
> C         |  6
```

Comment: Thank you - this looks very close. I'm getting an error in Hive on the t.id <> tt.id - "Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN"

Comment: is indeed a hive thing. Both queries aren't supported. I'm having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015035/hive-sql-both-left-and-right-aliases-encountered-in-join and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920692/nested-subquery-not-supported-in-hive  

If I don't get a Hive solution later today I'll accept your answer as the most helpful.

Comment: Try 1 more: `on t.placename = tt.placename  where tt.value between t.value - 0.5 and t.value + 0.5  and t.id <> tt.id` for the 1st query. I moved the between statement to the where clause.

Comment: I found this: *Complex expressions in ON clause are supported, starting with Hive 2.2.0 (see HIVE-15211, HIVE-15251). Prior to that, Hive did not support join conditions that are not equality conditions.* So if your version is prior to 2.2.0 then the join does not support between or <>. So move them to WHERE clause.

Comment: brilliant, thank you. this now runs. that snippet is correct - I am running prior to 2.2.0 (2.1.1)

I have replicated the result, will accept your answer.

I do have a quick variant if you don't mind - perhaps a separate question....

if I only want to find cases where the value is within this range for a duplicate id (i.e., case where id is not unique for a given placename - id = 1, value = 1, id = 1, value = 1.2 would both be returned - the condition should be met more than once, i.e., there should be multiple values that meet the condition for a given id)

Comment: This needs to be further explained with sample data and expected results just like you did in this question.